# having trouble populate dropdown in edit mode in grid view by function

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, viewstate

I am trying to populate the DDL by calling the function but it wont pass the If condition to go to function in here, already checked everything but it wont go to function 
**here is my code for grid view :**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="smOrderShipmentList" runat="server" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" 
                    BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black" 
                    GridLines="None" AllowPaging="false" 
                    OnRowDataBound="smOrderShipmentList_RowDataBound" 
        DataKeyNames="OrderShippingID" OnRowEditing="smOrderShipment_RowEditing" 
        onrowupdating="smOrderShipmentList_RowUpdating" 
        onrowcancelingedit="smOrderShipmentList_RowCancelingEdit">
                <Columns>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order Shipping ID" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
                        <ItemTemplate>

                          <a   href="javascript:collapseExpand('orderShippingID2-<%# Eval("OrderShippingID") %>');"> <asp:Label id="lblOrderShippingID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OrderShippingID")%>' /></a>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                   <%-- <asp:BoundField DataField="ShippingVia" HeaderText="Shipping Via" ItemStyle-Width="12%"/>--%>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shipping Via" ItemStyle-Width="12%" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <%--  <asp:DropDownList ID="lblShippingvia" runat="server" ><asp:ListItem>default</asp:ListItem>
                      </asp:DropDownList>--%>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblShippingvia" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ShippingVia") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlShippingvia" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"   />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

...

**I have tried two approach one direct to function and also use gridview databound but both get the same error:**

```
    protected void smOrderShipmentList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int orderShippingID = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "OrderShippingID"));

            GridView gvChild = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvOrderShippingDetail");
            var orderShippingDetailList = Shipping.GetOrderShippingDetailList("", orderShippingID, -1, true);
            gvChild.DataSource = orderShippingDetailList;
            gvChild.DataBind();
        }



        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlShippingvia");


            ddl.DataSource = bindshippmethods(((Label)e.Row.FindControl( "lblSellerID")).Text);

            ddl.DataBind();
            ddl.SelectedValue = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblShippingvia")).Text;


   }  
    protected ArrayList bindshippmethods(string sellerid)
    {

        ArrayList shmp = new ArrayList();
        foreach (var item in  Shipping.GetAllShippingMethodBySellerId(sellerid))
                {
                    shmp.Add(item.ShippingMethodName.ToString());

                    }

        return shmp;
    }



}`
```

Comment: protected void smOrderShipmentList_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            smOrderShipmentList.EditIndex =-1;
            LoadData();
         
        }

Comment: just fixed , only needed to bound the gridview / recall it in edit even

       protected void smOrderShipmentList_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            smOrderShipmentList.EditIndex =-1;
            LoadData();
         
        }